# Can't post comment on reddit using Postman: USER_REQUIRED error

Tags: java, rest, api, http, post

I'm trying to post a comment using Postman. I'm sending the following information:

**Headers:**

```
Authorization: "Bearer access_token"

Content-Type: " application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

User-Agent: "some u/user"
```

**Body:**

```
api_type: "json"

thing_id: "t3_9e04eo"

text: "some comment"
```

I'm sending this POST request to https://oauth.reddit.com/api/comment.

In return I get a `USER_REQUIRED error`:

​

```
{
    "json": {
        "errors": [
            [
                "USER_REQUIRED",
                "Please log in to do that.",
                null
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Why is that? I've passed an access_token and it was accepted as right (otherwise if I knowingly pass the wrong token I would get a 401 Unauthorized error).

What I have of the passwords:

My usual username:password pair

My script's app_id:app_secret pair

My access_token I was given in exchange for my app_id:app_secret pair.

I also tried to do this in Java, using `HttpURLConnection` class:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RedditParser {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            RedditParser redditParser = new RedditParser();
            redditParser.postAComment("sds", "fdfdf");
        } 

        public  void postAComment(String postID, String commentBody)  { 

             try  { 
                 String postLink = "https://oauth.reddit.com/api/comment"; 

                  URL loginURL = new URL(postLink); 
                  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) loginURL.openConnection();
                  JSONObject requestJSON = new JSONObject();
                  requestJSON.put("api_type", "json");
                  requestJSON.put("thing_id", "t3_9e04eo");
                  requestJSON.put("text", "a test comment");

                  connection.setDoOutput(true);

                  connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " +getAccessToken());  //getAccessToken returns correct(!) token; it's not the cause of the error
                  connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "script by /u/someuser");
                  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                  OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                  os.write(requestJSON.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                  os.close();

                  connection.connect();

                  System.out.println("Done comment");

                  InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                  String inputString = new Scanner(input, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
                  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(inputString);
                  System.out.println(inputString);
            }

            catch (Exception e)  {

                 System.out.println(e);
            }

       }
}
​
```

But I still get the error output:

```
Done comment
{"jquery": [[0, 1, "refresh", []], [0, 2, "attr", "find"], [2, 3, "call", [".error.USER_REQUIRED"]], [3, 4, "attr", "show"], [4, 5, "call", []], [5, 6, "attr", "text"], [6, 7, "call", ["Please log in to do that."]], [7, 8, "attr", "end"], [8, 9, "call", []]], "success": false}
```

What else do I need to add to the request to get rid of the error?

Comment: Are you sure that `requestProperty` is how to set a header? Also, you have a stray space in `Authorization `.

Comment: @parsecer Are you passing a Content-Length ?

Comment: I am wondering the same, If calls via postman works then this should work as well

Comment: Have you read the [OAuth2 quick start pages](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example)? In the curl example the request for the access token contains `"grant_type=password&username=reddit_bot&password=snoo"` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body data and additionally the app ID and app client secret. Do you request the access token accordingly?

Comment: I think you need send the cookie information received from token request to next request try adding extension of postman "Postman Interceptor" and try again once we get success with postman then we can change the code accordingly

Comment: If you want this question to be answered, please add information on how the access token request looks like.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/61qrqo/what_could_be_the_reason_for_this_error_json/) it seems like you need valid account credentials (username/password) as well as app credentials (id/secret). To me it makes sense that the token you got with just the app credentials would allow you to use the api (e.g. read comments) but results in an error when you post a comment. Posting should also require user credentials (a different token). So I think @dpr already provided the right answer.

Comment: @Wilfred Clement  I don't think I was passing it in Postman or in Java, but it doesn't seem to trigger anything, strangely (in my other question I was passing a request with an empty body, and that was when the server needed for the Content-Length: 0 property and refused to procede without it. But here the case was in the wrong access_token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information available I'd guess that you didn't provide user credentials in the token request but requested an [Application Only Token](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#application-only-oauth) instead. This type of token can probably not be used to post comments on reddit for obvious reasons.

To perform actions for a certain user you will need to request an access token like this:

```
reddit@reddit-VirtualBox:~$ curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=password&username=reddit_bot&password=snoo' --user 'p-jcoLKBynTLew:gko_LXELoV07ZBNUXrvWZfzE3aI' https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
{
    "access_token": "J1qK1c18UUGJFAzz9xnH56584l4", 
    "expires_in": 3600, 
    "scope": "*", 
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

That is provide user credentials as form data and use the app credentials for Basic authentication.

In general it's probably simpler to use one of the [API-Wrappers](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/API-Wrappers) that are already available for reddit. For Java the reddit wiki mentions [JRAW](https://github.com/mattbdean/JRAW) and [RedditJerk](https://github.com/euparkeria/RedditJerk).

Comment: Wow, you are a magician! I have already lost hope by now! Thank you! You were right. My mistake was in getting the wrong access_token: I got one using `grant_type=client_credentials` and only including a `APP_ID:APP_SECRET` as an Authorization, but I also had to include a `username` and `password` in the request's URL! Now I've got the correct access_token and posting a comment worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: I know of the wrappers, but since I'm new to the whole API thing, I wanted to do all things on my own to gain a better understanding. I hope to write a guide for others who want to do the same with Java once I figure out all the correct requests for the most necessary actions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to bounties and this one seems to have expired. In case it didn't get awarded, I tried to make up for it.

Comment: @parsecer, thanks, didn't answer for the bounty (only :-)). Hopefully the votings will not be reversed due to [serial upvoting detection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).